# awesome validation to validate imageview

Tags: android, validation, imageview

I want to check whether image is selected in `imageview` or not for that i have used

```
 protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

    if(requestCode==REQUEST_PICK_IMAGE && resultCode==RESULT_OK){

        path = data.getStringExtra(Constants.path);

        isImageSet=true;

        File imgFile=new File(path);
        path =imgFile.getPath();

        Glide.clear(ivIdProof);

        bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path);
        bitmap= ImageHandling.loadBitmapFromFile(this, path,400,400);
        ivIdProof.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

    }

    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);


}
```

awesome validation code

```
 awesomeValidation.addValidation(this, R.id.etIdentity, "^[A-Za-z\\s]{1,}[\\.]{0,1}[A-Za-z\\s]{0,}$", R.string.error_id1);
 awesomeValidation.addValidation(this, R.id.etIdentityNumber, "^[A-Za-z0-9\\s]{1,}[\\.]{0,1}[A-Za-z0-9\\s]{0,}$", R.string.error_id2);
```

and to check

```
if(awesomeValidation.validate() && path!=null){
.....
}
```

`awesomeValidation.validate()` is for validation of other fields.
how do i check `path!=null` using awesome validation and display error message

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
awesomeValidation.addValidation(this, R.id.your_view_id, "^null|$", R.string.error_your_id);
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the problem, it doesn't explain why or how it answers the question. Please include an explanation for your code, as that really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion

Comment: thanks @BalagurunathanMarimuthu, but i want to check `path!=null` condition where path is string variable. and if path is empty or null then display error message using awesome validation.

Answer (score 0):

You can try following :

```
    private boolean isImagePathValid(String path) {
    BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    options.inJustDecodeBounds =true;
    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path, options);
    if(options.outWidth !=-1&&options.outHeight !=-1)
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

And now from your code :

```
if(awesomeValidation.validate() && isImagePathValid){
```

.....
}